# Using .lib in c# application: 2 questions

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a `.lib` library and I'm trying to use it in C# application. I've made a `.dll` wrapper for it, but I have 2 questions:

1) How can I import c++ types, for example `msp_DEVHANDLE` to call my functions?

2) Calling open/close functions causes error like

> "mvlib.mv.Open is unavailable due to its protection level"

. But they are public and other 3 functions doesn't cause this error. What have I done wrong?

my wrapper dll:

mvlib.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace mvlib {

public ref class mv
{
public:     
    int GetNumberOfDevices(); 
    msp_ERROR Startup();
    msp_ERROR Cleanup();
    msp_DEVHANDLE Open(int n);
    msp_ERROR Close(msp_DEVHANDLE n);
};
}
```

mvlib.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "mvlib.h"

using namespace mvlib;

int mv::GetNumberOfDevices()
{
    return msp_GetNumberOfDevices();
}
msp_ERROR mv::Startup()
{
    return msp_Startup();
}
msp_ERROR mv::Cleanup()
{
    return msp_Cleanup();
}
msp_DEVHANDLE mv::Open(int n)
{
    return msp_Open(n);
}
msp_ERROR mv::Close(msp_DEVHANDLE n)
{
    return msp_Close(n);
}
```

Comment: 1) You have to declare a managed struct for them (using `StructLayout` for marshaling). You may also `DllImport` them and declare structs in C# but if exported interface is reach it'll easy become a pain. Much better to write a _proper_ managed interface using C++/CLI hiding all unmanaged things in a .NETish class hierarchy. 2) `Open`'s parameter `msp_DEVHANDLE` is private (and unmanaged) then that method will be _automatically_ `internal`, you should also have a warning for this.

Comment: You should not expose native types in your `ref class`, the C# code knows beans about it.  Could be as simple as using IntPtr instead and casting it back and forth from/to the native pointer type.  And the msp_Error should of course be raised as an exception.